# how to forbid connecting to localhost for ssh socks5 proxy

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, socks

when I start ssh socks5 proxy like that
`ssh user@localhost -D 0.0.0.0:1080`
it allows to anyone to connect to localhost like
`curl --socks5 server.com localhost:12345`
which can be a security issue for services that consider connections from localhost to be safe and ask no authentication (there are plenty of examples)

Question is, how to forbid ssh to connect to localhost on behalf of socks5 clients?

Comment: Why are you having your proxy listen on all the IPs?  -D 1080 without the 0.0.0.0 should limit it to localhost.  The IP address is optional.

Comment: @yoonix I want it to be available from everywhere for anybody, but I don't want anybody to connect to my own server, only to the internet through my server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ssh SOCKS implementation doesn't have many features. I'd use a more robust SOCKS proxy.

However, you can use iptables to accomplish this. Something like:

```
iptables -A input -i lo -m owner --uid-owner userid -j REJECT
```

Comment: If its not possible with ssh, that's an answer! Which socks proxy would you recommend if I want to not spend a lot of time configuring it?

Comment: I'd try the iptables rule. I don't have a socks proxy recommendation. If squid supported SOCKS I'd recommend it but it doesn't. 3proxy.ru looks like it supports acls but I have never used it.